# Angular custom filtering on two nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filtering, nested-lists

I have an array data like this:

```
[
{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Adams",
    calls: [
        {
            date: "2014-08-13",
            number: 123456789,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 1"
        },
        {
            date: "2014-08-18",
            number: 987654321,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 2"
        },
        {
            date: "2014-11-06",
            number: 123456543,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 1"
        },
        {
            date: "2014-10-15",
            number: 987654567,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 3"
        }
    ]
},
{
    firstName: "Jonnie",
    lastName: "Bravo",
    calls: [
        {
            date: "2014-05-09",
            number: 534535367,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 1"
        },
        {
            date: "2014-01-25",
            number: 089086464,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    firstName: "Ricky",
    lastName: "Lambert",
    calls: [
        {
            date: "2014-10-19",
            number: 147258369,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 3"
        },
        {
            date: "2014-11-01",
            number: 798908645,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 2"
        },
        {
            date: "2014-11-05",
            number: 312315367,
            operatorName: "Bla-Bla 3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I'm using Angular to loop through all the customers like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <span ng-repeat="call in customer.calls">
        <span class="name">{{ customer.name }}</span>
        <span class="info">{{ call.date }} - {{ call.number }} - {{ call.operatorName }}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

And the output is something like this:

> John Adams
>
> 2014-08-13 - 123456789 - Bla-Bla 1
>
> John Adams
>
> 2014-08-18 - 987654321 - Bla-Bla 2
>
> ...
>
> Jonnie Bravo
>
> 2014-05-09 - 534535367 - Bla-Bla 1
>
> ...
>
> Ricky Lambert
>
> 2014-11-05 - 312315367 - Bla-Bla 3

The problem I'm having now is that I want to filter the data to show all the users that called operator `Bla-Bla 1`. I searched about nested ng-repeats but nothing helped me at all. Keep in mind that I want my data to be shown like this.

Hope you understood me well. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
ng-if="call.operatorName=='Blabla 1'"
```

to second `ngRepeat`

Also you can filter your data with filters:

```
ng-repeat="call in customer.calls | filter:{operatorName:'Bla-Bla 1'}"
```

Or some custom:

```
ng-repeat="call in customer.calls | operatorF:'Bla-Bla 1'"

$scope.operatorF = function(){
  return function(calls, op) {
    if (!op) return calls;
    return calls.filter(function(call){
      return call.operatorName === op
    });
  };
}
```

or even better:

```
ng-repeat="call in customer.calls | filter:operator:'Bla-Bla 1'"

$scope.operator = function(call, op){
    if (!op) return true;
    return call.operatorName === op
};
```

And you cann't to do it without loop through.

Also you can manually check changes and update filtered set:

```
ng-repeat="call in customer.filteredCalls"

$scope.$watch('customer.calls', function(){
  $scope.customer.filteredCalls = $scope.customer.calls.filter(myFilterFn);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually I don't want to loop through everything and then show or hide it, so that's why I didn't chose this approach. :)

Comment: anyway you should loop through to filter it

Answer (score 0):

The ["filter"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) filter should work just fine:

```
<span ng-repeat="call in customer.calls | filter:{operatorName:'Bla-Bla 1'}">...</span>
```

Comment: Yeah this is it. But if I use some custom filtering this approach doesn't help me. For example if I check for customer firstName and called number, this doesn't help me.

Comment: Why don't you try reading the documentation I've linked? Providing multiple property values is just as easy as providing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a variety of different ways: using a `filter`, `ng-if`, or `ng-hide` are just a few of them.

It's an interesting topic to read on if you'd like to understand what's going on behind the scenes and what is best for your specific situation. I recommend checking out this link for a brief but good explanation of the trade-offs between a few of these different "filtering" mechanisms:

[filter vs ng-hide](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2487-filter-vs-nghide-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm)

Comment: Great, I will check the article. Maybe my question wasn't so good explained - I want to add some custom filter, because I have in mind to extend all the filtering functionality. So maybe in future I have to check for more "keys" in the calls' objects. In that case, is `filter`, `ng-if` or `ng-hide` good for me?

Comment: For simplicity sake, I would suggest you use the `filter`. You can pass in an object, string, or function to the filter parameter to evaluate multiple conditions. Something like `filter: {name: 'Jon', number: 123}`